# Get selected component in Unity Inspector window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

I'm trying to make a custom inspector with functionality that applies to all kind of built-in components.

What I'm really trying to do is get as a string the name of the property selected in blue in the inspector when I select it. Is there any way?
Example: When highlighting Local Position, is there any way to get "Transform Component - LocalPosition (0,0,0);
[image: Unity Editor highlighted element]

I tried reading the API to know if there's something that could help me but haven't had any luck. Also tried using `CustomEditor(TypeOf(Transform))` but I'm not able to access the values when highlighting.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would the [FocusInEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-Focus-Events.html) work for you?

You would have to add an event for every VisualElement or loop through the root and find all VisualElements and add the event to it. You could then get the name of the VisualElement and use that in the handling of the event.

From the documentation about the [focus events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-Focus-Events.html)

```
public void CreateGUI()
{
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.value = placeHolderText;
    rootVisualElement.Add(textField);

    textField.RegisterCallback<FocusInEvent>(OnFocusInTextField);
    textField.RegisterCallback<FocusOutEvent>(OnFocusOutTextField);
}

private void OnFocusInTextField(FocusInEvent evt)
{
    // If the text field just received focus and the user might want to write
    // or edit the text inside, the placeholder text should be cleared (if active)
    if (placeHolderMode)
    {
        var textField = evt.target as TextField;
        textField.value = "";
    }
}
```

I've added a working example as you said that it doesn't seem to be working with the editor. The editor implementation is working in my version of unity (2020.3.30f1) with the following code.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FocusScript : MonoBehaviour
{

}



using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

[CustomEditor(typeof(FocusScript))]
public class CustomEditorFocus : Editor
{
    public override VisualElement CreateInspectorGUI()
    {
        VisualElement myInspector = new VisualElement();

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.name = "test text field";
        textField.value = "test";
        textField.label = "test label";
        myInspector.Add(textField);

        textField.RegisterCallback<FocusInEvent>(OnFocusInTextField);
        return myInspector;
    }

    private void OnFocusInTextField(FocusInEvent evt)
    {
        var textField = evt.target as TextField;
        Debug.Log("Testing with field: " + textField.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been taking a look at this and sadly it looks like it only works with classes type of EditorWindow, not Editor(I could get the OnFocus on the full inspector, but not specific components)

Comment: It seems to be working in my version, i've added the example code i used that works on my version of unity. There might be a difference between versions and the implementation of uie but i'm not really sure of that. Make sure to add the CustomEditorFocus to an Editor folder. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Are you using the CreateInspectorGUI in the Editor?

Comment: I've been trying and I can add callbacks to the elements, but there's something else I need. Because what I'm trying to do is add it to already existing inspectors(Transform, BoxCollider, etc). I've tried making myInspector = base.CreateInspectorGUI() and then adding the textfield, but I can't make it to work. When I try to access the MyInspector, it's null. Do you know any way to get the base before adding my textfield?

Comment: As far as i know you can't really add events to the unity inspectors. You could create your own script and then hide the original component but i don't recommend that as you'll have a lot of overhead.

Comment: It sounds that what you're trying to do might not be the best solution or not really possible at this time. I'd rethink if there is another way to solve your problem.

The unity inspectors also might still use IMGUI or UIElements so you'll have to dig through it. I just don't recommend changing unity components, always build on top because you'll just keep running into walls. Been there and would not recommend it.

Comment: I'll see what I can really do tomorrow, and rethink how I'll handle this, thank you a lot!

Comment: Good luck! And happy to help.